# SVG textPath not working in Safari

Tags: html, svg, safari

I am trying to overlay a curved text over an image via inline SVG. It is working fine in Chrome, but Safari on iOS and desktop doesn't render the text.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 580 472" width="580" height="472" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <path id="curvedPath" d="M123.9,309.87s55.27,20.4,148.06,23.54c99.49,3.37,153.33-16.68,153.33-16.68"></path>
        <style type="text/css">
            #text {
                font-size: 24px;
                text-align: center;
                text-anchor: middle;
                fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            }
        </style>
    </defs>

    <image x="0" y="0" width="580" height="472" xlink:href="https://www.silvity.de/out/pictures/master/product/1/gravur-armband-swarovski-kristall-rosegold-schwarz-111106601.jpg"></image>

    <text id="text" class="Philosopher">
        <textPath href="#curvedPath" startOffset="50%" id="textcontent">Foobar StackOverflow</textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

This snippet is displaying the text "Foobar StackOverflow" in Chrome, but not in Safari.

The curve of the path doesn't matter, a straight line (`M10.100,L100.100`) isn't working either. The only way I can get the text to display is by embedding it directly in the `text` tag, such as `<text id="...">Foobar StackOverflow</text>`, which obviously isn't what I want.

Are there any restrictions in using `textPath` in Safari SVGs? How can I get this to render properly in both browsers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Safari only supports xlink:href and not the newer bare href.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 580 472" width="580" height="472" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">
    <defs>
        <path id="curvedPath" d="M123.9,309.87s55.27,20.4,148.06,23.54c99.49,3.37,153.33-16.68,153.33-16.68"></path>
        <style type="text/css">
            #text {
                font-size: 24px;
                text-align: center;
                text-anchor: middle;
                fill: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
            }
        </style>
    </defs>

    <image x="0" y="0" width="580" height="472" xlink:href="https://www.silvity.de/out/pictures/master/product/1/gravur-armband-swarovski-kristall-rosegold-schwarz-111106601.jpg"></image>

    <text id="text" class="Philosopher">
        <textPath xlink:href="#curvedPath" startOffset="50%" id="textcontent">Foobar StackOverflow</textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: I read that Safari didn't support `href` yet, but I was so sure that was referencing the `image` tag (which already used `xlink:href`), that I just didn't notice I was using `href` on the `textPath`. Thanks a lot!